# AWS CloudFormation WordPress Example Times Out

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am working on the walkthrough provided by AWS for [creating a pipeline for a WordPress site using CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-basic-walkthrough.html). Going through it the first time I got it work, but then I wanted to make some changes to the project, and try a few new things. In this case, I wanted to change my source to a GitHub repo, which has some other content for the site that I want to create. The only lines I change are in the resources WebServer block. Now it looks like this:

```
Resources:
  WebServer:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT15M
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          wordpress_install:
          - install_cfn
          - install_wordpress
          - configure_wordpress
        configure_wordpress:
          commands:
            01_set_mysql_root_password:
              command: !Sub |
                mysqladmin -u root password '${DBRootPassword}'
              test: !Sub |
                $(mysql ${DBName} -u root --password='${DBRootPassword}' >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null); (( $? != 0 ))
            02_create_database:
              command: !Sub |  
                mysql -u root --password='${DBRootPassword}' < /tmp/setup.mysql
              test: !Sub |
                $(mysql ${DBName} -u root --password='${DBRootPassword}' >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null); (( $? !=0))
            03_configure_wordpress:
              command: /tmp/create-wp-config
              cwd: /var/www/html/wordpress
        install_cfn:
          files:
            /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack= ${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
              group: root
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
            /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.WebServer.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServer --configsets wordpress_install --url https://stackbuilder.amazonaws.com
              group: root
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
          services:
            sysvinit:
              cfn-hup:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
                files:
                - /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf
                - /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf
        install_wordpress:
          files:
            /tmp/create-wp-config:
              content: !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe
                #cp /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php
                #git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Pinto18/base-wordpress-install.git /var/html/wordpress
                sed -i "s/'$connectstr_dbname'/'${DBName}'/g" wp-config.php
                sed -i "s/'$connectstr_dbusername'/'${DBUser}'/g" wp-config.php
                sed -i "s/'$connectstr_dbpassword'/'${DBPassword}'/g" wp-config.php                                    
              group: root
              mode: '000500'
              owner: root
            /tmp/setup.mysql:
              content: !Sub |
                CREATE DATABASE ${DBName};
                CREATE USER '${DBUser}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${DBPassword}';
                GRANT ALL ON ${DBName}.* TO '${DBUser}'@'localhost'; 
                FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
              group: root
              mode: '000400'
              owner: root
          packages:
            yum:
              git: []
              httpd: []
              mysql: []
              mysql-devel: []
              mysql-libs: []
              mysql-server: []
              php: []
              php-mysql: []
          services:
            sysvinit:
              httpd:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
              mysqld:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
          sources:
            /var/www/html: "https://github.com/Pinto18/base-wordpress-install/tarball/master"
```

My issue is that I keep getting a time out error saying "Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration" in the stack detail.

I'm not sure how I can get into the system logs for this instance. The instance doesn't seem to be created according to the EC2 management console. Also heard something about permissions, but I'm not sure how that works, especially since the instance isn't created.

Anyway, does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this error? Why is my instance not being created?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the default templates don't work.  For example, I tried the Rails one and encountered the same issue.  It seems Amazon created these a long time ago and somehow failed to keep them updated, and now there are just a bunch of broken templates to waste people's time.

The only way to diagnose this are to specify that you don't want the Stack rolled back if it fails to create, then to SSH in and check the logs on the server after it fails.  Unfortunately, nobody will ever bother to do this, because the whole point of trying the template was to not have to write things from scratch.  If Amazon wants to offer default templates they should make sure they work.  You might as well just create an Apache webserver and Google the directions to build Wordpress on a LAMP stack.